# Populate a Select List of Record Types based on Selected Record Owner's Profile

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, dynamic-visualforce

I am trying to create a visualforce form to create a new opportunity.  I want the first action to be selecting the opportunity owner (not the current running user - one user will be creating opportunities for a different user).  Based on the owner selection I need a picklist to be populated with the available record types for that owner.  The issue I am having is getting the query to refresh and populate the picklist:

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="opp_NewCSOpportunityController" tabStyle="Opportunity" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Demo"  subtitle="Custom Lookup" />

    <apex:form id="myForm">  
        <apex:PageBlock id="PageBlock"> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Custom Lookup">
                <apex:inputField id="owner" value="{!Opportunity.OwnerId}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="PageBlock" />
                </apex:inputField>


                        <apex:selectList value="{!rectypes}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                        </apex:selectList><p/>

                        <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" rerender="out" status="status"/>

                    <apex:outputPanel id="out">
                        <apex:actionstatus id="status" startText="testing...">
                            <apex:facet name="stop">
                                <apex:outputPanel>
                                    <p>You have selected:</p>
                                    <apex:dataList value="{!rectypes}" var="c">{!c}</apex:dataList>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:facet>
                        </apex:actionstatus>
                    </apex:outputPanel>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:PageBlock>
    </apex:form>      
</apex:page>
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class opp_NewCSOpportunityController {

    Opportunity opportunity;

    //If this is the first time the method is called,
    // it creates an empty record for the variable.

    public Opportunity getOpportunity() {
        if(opportunity == null) opportunity = new Opportunity();
        return opportunity;
    }

    //Select the owner of the new opportunity

    List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Profile.Name FRom User WHERE Id =:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('owner') LIMIT 1];

    public string profile{
        get{
            for(User u:users){
                profile = u.Profile.Name; 
                system.debug('u.Profile.Name');
            }       
            return profile;
        }
        set;
    }

    String[] rectypes = new String[]{};

        public PageReference test() {
            return null;
        }

    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        If(profile == 'Q-Sales-EI'){
            options.add(new SelectOption('Employee Insights','Employee Insights'));          
        }
        else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-Enterprise'){
            options.add(new SelectOption('Enterprise','Enterprise'));

        }
        else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-K12'){
            options.add(new SelectOption('K-12','K-12'));

        }
        else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-RS'){
            options.add(new SelectOption('Research Suite Corp','Research Suite Corp'));

        }
        else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-SLG'){
            options.add(new SelectOption('Enterprise','Enterprise'));

        }
        else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-Academic'){
            options.add(new SelectOption('Academic','Academic'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Enterprise','Enterprise'));
        }          
        return options;
    }

    public String[] getRectypes() {
        return rectypes;
    }

    public void setRectypes(String[] rectypes) {
        this.rectypes = rectypes;
    }

    // This method cancels the wizard, and returns the user to the 
    // Opportunities tab
    public PageReference cancel() {
        PageReference opportunityPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(opportunity).view();
        opportunityPage.setRedirect(true);
        return opportunityPage; 
    }

    // This method performs the final save, and
    // then navigates the user to the detail page for the new
    // opportunity.
    public PageReference save() {

        // Create the opportunity. 
        insert opportunity;

        // Finally, send the user to the detail page for 
        // the new opportunity.

        PageReference opptyPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(opportunity).view();
        opptyPage.setRedirect(true);

        return opptyPage;
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query user everytime your owner change on layout

```
 public string profile{
        get{
            for(User u: [SELECT Id, Profile.Name FRom User WHERE Id =:Opportunity.OwnerId LIMIT 1]){
                profile = u.Profile.Name; 
                system.debug('u.Profile.Name');
            }       
            return profile;
        }
        set;
    }
```

You need to update you `getItem` section as

```
public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        for(User u: [SELECT Id, Profile.Name FRom User WHERE Id  =:Opportunity.OwnerId LIMIT 1]){
                profile = u.Profile.Name;

    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
    If(profile == 'Q-Sales-EI'){
        options.add(new SelectOption('Employee Insights','Employee Insights'));          
    }
    else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-Enterprise'){
        options.add(new SelectOption('Enterprise','Enterprise'));

    }
    else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-K12'){
        options.add(new SelectOption('K-12','K-12'));

    }
    else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-RS'){
        options.add(new SelectOption('Research Suite Corp','Research Suite Corp'));

    }
    else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-SLG'){
        options.add(new SelectOption('Enterprise','Enterprise'));

    }
    else If(profile == 'Q-Sales-Academic'){
        options.add(new SelectOption('Academic','Academic'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Enterprise','Enterprise'));
    }          
    return options;
}
```

Also for everything you have created get method.In get method its hard to manage code execution because required or not whenever page `rerender` they execute again. increase the CPU time and in your case will increase number of SOQL as well.

Comment: I changed the code but the picklist still isn't populating.

Comment: What would you recommend instead of using the get method?

Comment: @user35075 create void methods and do processing in them. Also for profile put this code inside getitems method.